# Mapred Task Timeout

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I have written a Map only job, where data is written from one HBase table to another, after some processing. But in my `setup` method of mapper, I am loading data from a file which takes more time than my `mapred.task.timeout` configuration.

I read the explanation given [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/mapred-default.html). My question is,

1) will there be no communication between the task and the task tracker in the middle of a setup phase?

2) How to update ***status string***??

Answer (score 3):

Job wont timeout as long as there is a progress

Progress reporting is important, as Hadoop will not fail a task that’s making progress. All of the following operations constitute progress:

- • Reading an input record (in a mapper or reducer)
- • Writing an output record (in a mapper or reducer)
- • Setting the status description on a reporter (using Reporter’s
  setStatus() method)
- • Incrementing a counter (using Reporter’s incrCounter() method)
- • Calling Reporter’s progress() method

so if you keep on doing any of this at a nominal interval that job wont be killed.